# How to prove that $G$ is an Abelian group?

Tags: group-theory

Does someone have any hint to attack this group theoretic problem... or a way to start:

Let $(G,.)$ be a group having the property that there exists an integer $n \geq 1$ such the map $f_n: \: G \longrightarrow G, \: f_n(x)=x^n$ is injective and the map $f_{n+1}:\: G \longrightarrow G, \: f_{n+1}=x^{n+1}$ is a surjective endomorphism.

Prove that $G$ is an a Abelian group.

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to demonstrate the existence in $G$ of an element whose order is the exponent $n=mp^{\alpha}$, $m$ not divisible by $p$, so $G$ would be Abelian... I’m trying to use the fact that the kernel of $f_n$ is trivial and that the image of $G$ by $f_{n+1}$ is $G$ itself to build something but I didn’t get any results for the moment.

Comment: @3809525720: Is it given that $G$is finite?

Comment: No it’s not. $G$ could be infinite indeed.

Comment: For those who cite lack of context etc - bear in mind that the question asks for a hint or a way in rather than a full solution ...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @MarkBennet; I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $(ab)^{n+1}=a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$.

This implies

$$(ba)^n=a^nb^n\qquad (1)$$

(cancel $a$ on the left and $b$ on the right in the previous equality). Let $A$  denote $a^{-1}$.

Then apply (1)  to $((ab)A)^n$. We get

$$ab^nA=(abA)^n=A^n(ab)^n=A^nb^na^n$$

(in this sequence of equalities the first one is an obvious fact and the second and the third  are applications of (1) ). Therefore $a^{n+1}$ commutes with $b^n$.

By surjectivity  of $x\mapsto x^{n+1}$ we have: $b^n$ is central.

Hence $(ba)^n=a^nb^n= b^na^n=(ab)^n$. By injectivity of $x\mapsto x^n$  then $ab=ba$.QED

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary, then $(ab)^{n+1}=a(ba)^nb$. By surjectivity of $f_{n+1}$, there exists an $x\in G$ such that $x^{n+1}=(ba)^n$. With this you can show that $(ab)^n=x^{n+1}=(ba)^n$ and this implies under your assumptions that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: How to get "$(ab)^n=x^{n+1}=(ba)^n$"?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was searching for examples of such groups. They are difficult to find. In a discussion on a forum, a professor suggested me the following: $G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ with $n=1$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. It works when you choose $n$ and $n+1$ with $\gcd(n,m)=\gcd(n+1,m)=1$. I’m working on other examples. Thank you once again to those who answered !